# Where are the audio files of "Voice Memos" stored on macOS Mojave?

Tags: mojave, voice-memo

There are no options for Voice Memos application to specify path to save.

Searching for the recording name also did not reveal any file in Finder.

I wish to edit the audio file in Audacity but I need to find the saved file first.

Comment: Something to add...i found an easier way to get the recording as file. Simply drag and drop the file to desktop.

Comment: stupid little program, isnt it

Comment: @Koder you're legend

Answer (score 38):

.m4a files created by Voice Memos can be found at

> $HOME/Library/Application Support/com.apple.voicememos/Recordings

Inside that folder is an .m4a file of the actual recording, prefaced with a string of numbers. The file is **not** saved with the name you give the memo in the interface, unfortunately.

[image]

The Voice Memos interface allows you to send the audio file through Messages, Mail, or export it to Notes or AirDrop:

[image]

.

Comment: This no longer works....that folder does not exist. Anyone have a new solution? [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvunI.png).

Comment: From your screenshot, I can see you’re using the wrong path. Use `/Users/your_username/Library/Application Support/com.apple.voicememos/Recordings` I’ve updated my answer to be more specific. In Unix pathnames, `~/` represents the root level of your user account.

Comment: It's the `Library` folder under your home folder, not under the root `/`.

Comment: I don't have that folder. I'm using Catalina

Comment: @whamsicore - Perhaps it has moved to another path entirely with the release of Catalina. I'm not using a Mac with 10.15.x at the moment. I'll take a look next week sometime when I get back to the office. Have you done a little exploration yourself?

Comment: @whamiscore it's there, just hidden at the com.apple.voicememos folder in the UI.  Use the Terminal, it's there.

Comment: I can confirm I see this in Catalina. `ll $HOME/Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.voicememos/Recordings`

Comment: yes, the files are in `$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.voicememos/Recordings`, but if you drag and drop them from the interface of Voice Memos the names (that you might have changed in the meanwhile) are preserved, while in the above directory files have the name they started with (and the name in the data inside). I also checked that the drag-and-drop only changes the name of the copy, not the data.