# How to sync iPhone Voice Memos to the Mac via USB without using iCloud?

Tags: usb, data-synchronization, catalina, data-transfer, voice-memo

I have no interest in iCloud for syncing sizeable data like Voice Memos. It is quickest for me to just connect my iPhone to my Mac via the USB cable and do my syncing that way.

Many changes have occurred in recent times, with iTunes now completely replaced on the Mac.

On Catalina 10.15.2 and iOS 13.3, this is what it currently looks like:

There are many Voice memos on my iPhone:

[image]

But on my macOS Finder I do not see a mention anywhere of Voice Memos being present on my iPhone:

[image]

[image]

Similarly, in my Mac's Music.app there is simply nothing showing up as detected on my iPhone:

[image]

As for Voice Memos.app, there appears to be no connection to the iOS counterpart whatsoever, it is empty:

[image]

Has Apple abandoned USB transfer functionality between the iPhone and the Mac?

How can I do this? Do we now have to use third party tools like [AnyTrans](https://www.imobie.com/anytrans/) despite these both being Apple devices?

Answer (score 0):

If you do have any voice memos stored on your computer whether from backing it up the old way in iTunes or via iCloud, you can go and hunt for the files inside your computer. However, Apple does not recommend messing with them directly. However, if you do want to find them and be able to, for example, drag and drop them onto a hard drive, you need to search for: "com.apple.voicememos" in Finder. These files are kept hidden in a Libary under your user name. To see them you need to clip Command+Shift+.

Good luck...!

Comment: The Voice Memos files the OP is looking for are on an iPhone presently, and need to be transferred to a Macintosh. My answer [here at Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340647/where-are-the-audio-files-of-voice-memos-stored-on-macos-mojave/340662#340662) shows how to find the files on a Mac.