# How to find the folder com.apple.voicememos on High Sierra?

Tags: iphone, itunes, finder, high-sierra, voice-memo

I want to locate the folder `com.apple.voicememos` (cf. paths indicated [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340647/where-are-the-audio-files-of-voice-memos-stored-on-macos-mojave/340662#340662) and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250178973)) in order to obtain the sound files of voice memos that are visible in iTunes. However, on macOS High Sierra, there is no such folder in `Library/Application Support`.

I also do not find this folder when searching in Finder.

Comment: In **Terminal**, run the following _command_ and see what it returns: `find / -type d -iname '*com.apple.voicememos*' 2>/dev/null`

Comment: @user3439894 It returns nothing.

Comment: **VoiceMemos.app** does not exist in **macOS High Sierra**. It was first introduced in **macOS Mojave**.

Comment: See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340647/where-are-the-audio-files-of-voice-memos-stored-on-macos-mojave/340662#340662) for versions of macOS later than High Sierra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the sound files of voice memos in High Sierra, check under `/Users/{yourusername}/music/itunes/itunes media/voice memos`. You need to put that path in between double quotes if you use this path along with the `cd` command in a terminal window. Or you can simply paste it into the popup window that would appear after choosing Go -> "Go to Folder" within Finder and then click on Go.

If that folder turns out not to exist on your iMac but if you somehow have one or more self-recorded voice memos on your iTunes, right-click on any of them and choose "Show in Finder". Then right-click on the sound file that appears in the Finder window to open up and click on "Get Info". The "Where" field in the window to open up should show where the sound file is located.

---

The Voice Memos application is not available standalone in macOS High Sierra (10.13), which is why it is not under that same name. It is only available in Mojave (10.14) and later.